(BUG) ExtJS's Grid component has a style problem when the page is scaled by a factor other than an integer
When there are locked columns in the Grid component of ExtJS, if the page is scaled by a factor other than an integer, there is a problem with the styling of the locked columns, and the spacer lines will not line up.
How can I fix this style issue please?


ExtJS Classic with Neptune theme, demo code is here.
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [
        { 'name': 'Lisa',  "email":"lisa@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-111-1224"  },
        { 'name': 'Bart',  "email":"bart@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1234" },
        { 'name': 'Homer', "email":"home@simpsons.com",  "phone":"555-222-1244"  },
    ]
});
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Styles have errors when the page non-integer scaling',
    columnLines: true,
    store: store,
    features: [{
      ftype: 'summary',
      dock: 'bottom',
    }],
    columns: [
        { xtype: 'rownumberer', width: 30, summaryType: 'count' },
        { text: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', width: 100, locked: true },
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', width: 150 },
        { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone', width: 120 }
    ],
    height: 200,
    layout: 'fit',
    fullscreen: true,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

The demo code can be demonstrated here:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor
UPDATE: 12 Apr 2024
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3qtb
Zoom 100% (bug does not exist)

Zoom 125% (the bug appears)


Hmm, it is strange but I cannot reproduce your bug, check this out: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3qtb Also what do you mean "other than an integer"? You can update your fiddle link and show your way.

@sergey-bogdanov, Thanks for the help with the test, I'm talking about the zoom feature in Chrome that zooms to 125% or 150% or 175%...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcXBwxLYVUE
or
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPnr7baL69Q

@sergey-bogdanov
On my computer, zoom 100% or zoom 200%, this bug does not exist!
But when I zoom the browser to 125% or 150% or 175%, the bug appears!

@sergey-bogdanov
I've added 2 test screenshots to the main post based on your fiddle link.
